# Highlight code between specified tags

Tags: font-lock, major-mode, highlighting, region

how can I write extension for existing major mode, e.g. dart-mode to highlight block of codes. For example:

```dart
// $done>
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
// $done<

import 'package:android_id/android_id.dart';
import 'package:banagher/gen/i18n/strings.g.dart';
import 'package:banagher/gen/models/meta.pbgrpc.dart';
```

I code that is located between tags `// $done>` and `//$done<` to have green background color.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Just add `font-lock` rules that do what you want. Search this site for tag `font-lock` using `[font-lock]` in the Search bar. This question may even be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this with the following code:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'dart-mode
                        '(("\\<done\\$\n\\(\\(\\(.*?\n\\)*?.*?\\)\\)\\/\\/ end\\$" 1 font-lock-done-region-face prepend)))
```

It doesn't work perfectly but it's enough for my need.